# How do you use gcc to generate assembly code in Intel syntax?

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, intel-syntax

The `gcc -S` option will generate assembly code in AT&T syntax, is there a way to generate files in Intel syntax?  Or is there a way to convert between the two?

Comment: you can convert single instructions easily in the shell with llvm-mc: `echo "packsswb mm0,[bp+si-0x54]" | llvm-mc-3.2 -x86-asm-syntax=intel` gives `packsswb -84(%bp,%si), %mm0`

Answer (score 239, accepted):

#### Use `-masm=intel`

```
gcc -S -masm=intel -Og -fverbose-asm test.c
```

That works with GCC, and Clang 3.5 and later.  [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html#index-masm_003ddialect):

> - `-masm=dialect`
>   Output asm instructions using selected dialect.  Supported choices
>   are intel or att (the default one).  Darwin does not support intel.

---

For macOS, note that by default, the `gcc` command actually runs Clang unless you've installed actual GCC (e.g. from Brew).  Modern clang supports `-masm=intel` as a synonym for this, but [this always works with clang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11957826/950427):

```
clang++ -S -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel test.cpp
```

Note that [until clang 14](https://reviews.llvm.org/D113707), this does *not* change how clang processes inline `asm()` statements, [unlike for GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347909/can-i-use-intel-syntax-of-x86-assembly-with-gcc).

These are the options used by Matt Godbolt's Compiler Explorer site by default: https://godbolt.org/
See also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output) for other options and tips for getting asm output that's interesting to look at.

Comment: Despite its incorrect filename att2intel.sed, that sed script converts the other way, from Intel to ATT.

Comment: Anyone have a solution for Mac?

Comment: Clang cannot currently consume Intel syntax. See [LLVM Bug 24232: \[X86\] Inline assembly operands don't work with .intel_syntax](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24232). Also, Clang ignores `prefix`/`noprefix` (not sure if it matters if Clang consumes the assembly).

Comment: gcc -S -masm=intel test.c   is work on MacOS as well

Answer (score 22):

The

```
gcc -S -masm=intel test.c
```

Does work with me. But i can tell another way, although this has nothing to do with running gcc. 
Compile the executable or the object code file and then disassemble the object code in Intel asm syntax with objdump as below:

```
 objdump -d --disassembler-options=intel a.out
```

This might help.

Comment: same as objdump -d -M intel

Comment: The output from this is easier to read than the output from gcc. Great tip (even 13 years later).

Answer (score 6):

I have this code in CPP file:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int a = 0;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    asm("mov eax, 0xFF");
    asm("mov _a, eax");
    printf("Result of a = %d\n", a);
    getch();
    return 0;
 };
```

That's code worked with this GCC command line:

```
gcc.exe File.cpp -masm=intel -mconsole -o File.exe
```

It will result *.exe file, and it worked in my experience.

```
Notes:
immediate operand must be use _variable in global variabel, not local variable.
example: mov _nLength, eax NOT mov $nLength, eax or mov nLength, eax

A number in hexadecimal format must use at&t syntax, cannot use intel syntax.
example: mov eax, 0xFF -> TRUE, mov eax, 0FFh -> FALSE.
```

That's all.

Comment: Doesn't work on my Fedora: `$ gcc -S -masm=intel -mconsole a.c -o a.out
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mconsole’`

Comment: Works in cygwin.  Assembly goes in as intel, comes out as intel in the .s file. If you use `-o a.out` you won't get an .s file.

Comment: This is a broken way to use inline asm, and will break with optimization enabled.  You modify `eax` and `a` in asm statements without telling the compiler about it.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info for guides.  `-masm=intel` is the correct option to make the syntax *inside* the asm templates work, but using Basic asm instead of Extended with constraints is very wrong.