# Microsoft Assembler to GNU Assembler conversion

Tags: visual-studio, arm, gnu, gnu-assembler, assembly

I have an ARM assembly code that compiles well with Visual Studio. I would like to now use the same ARM assembly code and compile it with GNU Assembler. As you know the syntax of both assemblers are different. I was wondering if there is any tool that can convert from these Assembly syntaxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [How do you use gcc to generate assembly code in Intel syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199966/how-do-you-use-gcc-to-generate-assembly-code-in-intel-syntax)