# Easy way to convert c code to x86 assembly?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, programming-languages, assembly, x86

Is there an easy way (like a free program) that can covert c/c++ code to x86 assembly?

I know that any c compiler does something very similar and that I can just compile the c code and then disassemble the complied executable, but that's kind of an overkill, all I want is to convert a few lines of code.

Does anyone know of some program that can do that?

EDIT: I know that GCC compiler does that but it's AT&T syntax and I'm looking for the Intel syntax (not sure if it's called intel syntax or not). The AT&T syntax looks a bit like gibberish to me and some commands use operands in reverse order and not how I'm used to and it can get really confusing.

Comment: The compiler does exactly that. Your compiler will come with an option to show you the assembler output. Perhaps you might consider reading its manual? I know this is the weekend, but really....

Comment: Weekend's long over where I am :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Gcc can do it with the -S switch, but it will be disgustingly ugly at&t syntax.

Comment: But you can add the `-masm=intel` switch

Comment: Use `clang -S -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel` on Mac OS X

Answer (score 46):

GCC can output Intel syntax assembly using the following command line:

```
gcc -S input.c -o output.asm -masm=intel
```

Comment: I'd recommend at least `-Og` optimization if you're compiling small functions and want to see how the compiler does things.  See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) for that and more, e.g. on writing small C functions that compile to asm that's interesting to look at, e.g. take args and return a value.   e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/9bWKGKdWY (Godbolt also makes it easy to try other compiler versions and ISAs).  With the default `-O0`, the asm is full of store/load instructions that can be harder follow than registers.

Answer (score 13):

gcc will generate assembly if you pass it the `-S` option on the command line.

Microsoft Visual C++ will do the same with the `/FAs` option.

Comment: does the ms visual c++ also use the at&t syntax or the Intel syntax?

Comment: @Bob:  VC++ emits beautiful Intel syntax assembly.

Comment: @Bob:  You may also be able to get gcc to generate Intel syntax assembly:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199966/how-do-you-use-gcc-to-generate-assembly-code-in-intel-syntax

Answer (score 7):

The [`lcc`](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/software/lcc/) compiler is a multiplatform cross-compiler.  You can get it to produce Intel syntax assembly code by

```
lcc -S -Wf-target=x86/win32 foo.c
```

I find assembly code from `lcc` significantly easier to read than what `gcc` spits out nowawadays.

Answer (score 4):

Your compiler is already doing that as you've stated, and most likely will have an option to stop before assembling.

For GCC, add the `-S` flag.

```
gcc -S x.c
cat x.s
```

---

**Edit:** If your program is pretty short, you could use the online service at https://gcc.godbolt.org/.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using gcc as a compiler, you can compile with the -S option to produce assembly code.  see http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq8_20.html

Answer (score 0):

As many people point out most compilers will do that. If you don't like the syntax,a bit of work with awk or sed should be able to translate. Or I'd be surprised if there wasn't a program that did that bit for you already written somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In VC++ the following command can be used to list the assembly code.

> cl /FAs a.c

Answer (score 0):

notice 
every architecture has its own unique names and even build differently 
now when you know the stacks involved using  **asm** **volatile** 
would b the perfect solution