# Why won't simple inline assembly function work correctly in GCC?

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, inline-assembly

I have a simple inline assembly function, which works fine in **MSVC**, but for some reason refuses to work under **Apple GCC 4.2.1** (i386 arch, forced 32-bit mode). Fortunately, much more complex assembly functions work fine, however I can't fathom why won't this one work... Unfortunately, I can't debug it - by the look of things there is no registers window in **XCode 4.0.2** (it was in **3.2** versions).

**I'm positive that the problem is not related with Intel style assembly**.

```
int Convert(double value)
{
     _asm
     {
         fld value
         push eax
         fistp dword ptr [esp]
         pop eax
     }

// The returned value is insane
}
```

Comment: why are you trying to do this in assembly? float a = 3.14; int b = *(int *)&a; does the same. Also, you pass in a double but convert it as 32-bit.

Comment: @dascandy: That line of code is undefined behaviour.

Comment: That's a point. Is using inline assembly defined behaviour?

Comment: That's a great joke, Dascandy!

Comment: @dascandy: Yes, GCC and clang define the behaviour of inline asm (as long as the the constraints actually describe to the optimizer what the asm template does).  Or for `asm{}` blocks, it's up to the compiler to infer which registers are stepped on and which C++ objects may be read or modified.  But anyway, you're right that using inline asm for this is horrible, and very inefficient this way; use `memcpy` which will inline.  (Not a pointer-cast hack; `g++ -fstrict-aliasing` is the default with optimization enabled.)

Answer (score 8):

> Fortunately, much more complex assembly functions work fine[...]

Are these also inline assembly functions? Because GCC uses a [completely different](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html) syntax for inline assembler. You can make the syntax look more familiar though, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Assembler#Criticism).

```
1     int Convert(double value) 
2     {   
3         int result; 
4         __asm__ __volatile__ ( 
5             "fist %0\n\t" 
6             : "=m" (result) 
7             : "t" (value) 
8             );          
9         return result; 
10     }
```

Is how I would do it. `=m` specifies that we want a memory operand to store the result in (we don't want a register as `fist` doesn't work with those). `t` specifies that the value is passed on the stack top, that also ensures proper cleanup for us.

EDIT:

Another thing to try, assuming gcc with xcode allows the same kind of inline assembler as msvc, is:

```
 int Convert(double value)
 {
      int result;
      _asm
      {
          fld value
          push eax
          fistp dword ptr [esp]
          pop eax
          mov [result], eax
      }
      return result;
 }
```

That should also shut up the warnings about missing return values you're probably getting. It might simply be that it is more strict about allowing you to return values from assembler blocks by writing eax than msvc.

Comment: Side note: GCC has a switch to allow for different assembler dialects, doesn't it? It allows both AT&T and Intel syntax.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Are you thinking about `gcc -masm=intel -S`? That (at least on my machine) simply puts a `.intel_syntax noprefix` (as described by the wikipedia link in my post) at the top of the file.

Comment: Yeah, that one. I just thought that might be useful to know when you're porting from some other codebase and don't want to have to rewrite the assembler part.

Comment: Yeah, AT&T is extremely confusing at first :) (Old [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199966/how-do-you-use-gcc-to-generate-assembly-code-in-intel-syntax) about it.

Comment: Yes, the problem here is that MSVC supports falling off the end of a non-`void` function containing an `asm` block, and using EAX as the return value, even when inlining the wrapper function.  Clang's `-fasm-blocks` support doesn't support that.  You'd have to store EAX to a named variable and return that, introducing yet another store/reload because that MSVC-style asm-blocks syntax is horribly inefficient.  Of course in reality you should just use `memcpy` (or C++20 `std::bit_cast`) which will fully inline to whatever asm is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine for me with Apple gcc 4.2.1:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int Convert(double value)
{
     _asm
     {
         fld value
         push eax
         fistp dword ptr [esp]
         pop eax
     }
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = Convert(42.0);

    printf("i = %d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin10
Configured with: /var/tmp/gcc/gcc-5666.3~123/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin10 --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin10- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin10 --target=i686-apple-darwin10 --with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
$ gcc -Wall -m32 -O3 -fasm-blocks convert.c -o convert
convert.c: In function ‘Convert’:
convert.c:14: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
$ ./convert
i = 42
```

My guess is that you are inadvertently compiling for 64 bit. Take a look at the build transcript in Xcode and make sure you can see `-m32` when compiling this code - it's easy for a setting to get overriden somewhere in the project. You can also try building and running my code example above from the command line to make sure it works with your toolchain.

Comment: I'm surprised this didn't break with optimization enabled!  Definitely a happens-to-word; only MSVC supports falling off the end of non-void functions where an `asm` block left a value in EAX. Mainline clang `-fasm-blocks` will normally break code like this, not treating the asm statement like it had an `"=a"` EAX output when inlining the function containing the asm statement. [Does \_\_asm{}; return the value of eax?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36802822) / [Why doesn't this MSVC asm block have a ret, or the non-void function have a return?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/120965371)

Answer (score 1):

GCC's syntax requires you to specify which variables you're going to use inside the assembly coded portion.  The posted code doesn't do that, and may in fact be operating on random memory instead of the variables you expect to.

Additionally, GCC has some ability to use calling conventions other than the standard "pass everything on the stack" (eg., fastcall and tail recursive calls).  The assembly code posted assumes that everything is passed on the stack.  You may have a mismatch between what your assembly code expects and what GCC is doing.

The assembly code in user786653's answer avoids these problems.

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me in Xcode 4.0.2 (with warnings about control reaching end of non-void function). I created the project in 3.2.6 and when I first loaded it into Xcode 4.0.2 it wouldn't compile. I finally got it to compile after I set the Architecture to 32-bit, the Valid Architecture to i386, and the compiler to GCC 4.2. With the compiler set to LLVM GCC 4.2, it runs but the function returns 0.

[image: Compiler set to LLVM GCC 4.2]
[image: Compiler set to GCC 4.2]