# Does __asm{}; return the value of eax?

Tags: c, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

Simple question. The function `asm` in C is used to do inline assembly in your code. But what does it return? Is it the conventional `eax`, and if not, what does it return?

Comment: It depends on the compiler, but AFAIK it is not a function and it doesn't return anything, so `int i = __asm__()` is just an invalid construct

Comment: Which compiler? Which processor? Most processors don't have an eax register.

Comment: True. Okay assuming it's visual studio compiler (not sure which one is that) and a 32 bit intel processor.

Comment: `__asm__();` doesn't work at all in Visual Sudio, no matter what processor.  It's GCC syntax, which also works on ICC and Clang, but not MSVC.

Comment: There are CPUs out there that don't even have an eax register (yes, really!). So that is not an inherent standard C feature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`__asm__` itself does not return a value. C standard does not define how `__asm__` should handle the return value, so the behavior might be different between compilers. You stated that Visual Studio example is valid, but Visual Studio uses `__asm`. `__asm__` is used at least by GCC.

## Visual Studio

To get the result in a C program, you can place return value to `eax` in the assembly code, and return from the function. The caller will receive contents of `eax` as the return value.  This is supported even with optimization enabled, even if the compiler decides to inline the function containing the `__asm{}` block.

It avoids a store/reload you'd otherwise get from `mov`ing the value to a C variable in the asm and returning that C variable, because MSVC inline asm syntax doesn't support inputs/outputs in registers (except for this return-value case).

[Visual Studio 2015 documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5sds75we.aspx):

```
int power2( int num, int power )
{
   __asm
   {
      mov eax, num    ; Get first argument
      mov ecx, power  ; Get second argument
      shl eax, cl     ; EAX = EAX * ( 2 to the power of CL )
   }
   // Return with result in EAX
   // by falling off the end of a non-void function
}
```

clang `-fasm-blocks` supports the same inline-asm syntax but does *not* support falling off the end of a non-`void` function as returning the value that an `asm{}` block left in EAX/RAX.  Beware of that if porting MSVC inline asm to clang.  It will break horribly when compiled with optimization enabled (function inlining).

## GCC

[GCC inline assembly HOWTO](https://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html) does not contain a similar example. You can't use an implicit return as in Visual Studio, but fortunately you don't need to because GNU C inline asm syntax allows specifying outputs in registers.  No hack is needed to avoid a store/reload of an output value.

The HOWTO shows that you can store the result to C variable inside the assembly block, and return value of that variable after the assembly block has ended.  You can even use `"=r"(var)` to let the compiler pick its choice of register, in case EAX isn't the most convenient after inlining.

An example of an (inefficient) string copy function, returning value of `dest`:

```
static inline char * strcpy(char * dest,const char *src)
{
int d0, d1, d2;
__asm__ __volatile__(  "1:\tlodsb\n\t"
                       "stosb\n\t"
                       "testb %%al,%%al\n\t"
                       "jne 1b"
                     : "=&S" (d0), "=&D" (d1), "=&a" (d2)
                     : "0" (src),"1" (dest) 
                     : "memory");
return dest;
}
```

(Note that `dest` isn't actually an output from the inline asm statement.  The matching constraint for the dummy output operands tells the compiler the inline asm destroyed that copy of the variable so it needs to preserve it across the asm statement on its own somehow.)

---

If you omit a `return` statement in a non-`void` function with optimization enabled, you get a warning like `warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]` and recent GCC/clang won't even emit a `ret`; it assumes this path of execution is never taken (because that would be UB).  It doesn't matter whether or not the function contained an `asm` statement or not.

Comment: Now I just realized why missing 'return' in C/C++ isn't error always... Ofc if your 1 example is correct ;)) (going to check)

Comment: Note that clang's `-fasm-blocks` support for MSVC-style `__asm { }` blocks does *not* support falling off the end of a non-`void` function as returning the value that asm left in EAX/RAX.  Only MSVC itself supports that (including after inlining).

Comment: See also [Why doesn't this MSVC asm block have a ret, or the non-void function have a return?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68438183)

Answer (score 3):

It's unlikely; per the C99 spec, under J3 Implementation-defined behaviour:

> The asm keyword may be used to insert assembly language directly into
>   the translator output (6.8). The most common implementation is via a  statement of the form:
>
> `asm ( character-string-literal );`

So it's unlikely that an implementor is going to come up with an approach that both inserts the assembly language into the translator output and also generates some additional intermediary linking code to wire a particular register as a return result.

It's a keyword, not a function.

E.g. GCC uses `"=r"`-type constraint semantics to allow you in your assembly to have write access to a variable. But you ensure the result ends up in the right place.