# What type of assembly does gcc output with the -S flag

Tags: gcc, assembly, nasm

The title of the post is the question. I can see it is not assembly language ment for the NASM assembler. What assemlby language is gcc's assembly output ment for?

Comment: Look up the difference between ["AT&T syntax" and "Intel syntax"](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in AT&T syntax of the machine you're compiling on, while NASM uses Intel syntax.

`-S -masm=intel` will fix it: [How do you use gcc to generate assembly code in Intel syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199966/how-do-you-use-gcc-to-generate-assembly-code-in-intel-syntax)

Answer (score 3):

Mainly, two assembly flavors exists.

- Intel syntax
- AT&T (GAS) syntax

GCC usually outputs assembly using the AT&T (GAS) syntax, while NASM uses the Intel syntax.

On some platforms, you can generate assembly in Intel syntax using:

```
-masm=intel
```

Unfortunately, this is not supported everywhere.
For instance, if using OS X, only the AT&T syntax is supported.

Comment: @ninjalj Right, but the NASM syntax is actually based on the Intel one. It's a kind of «simplified» Intel syntax.

Comment: You don't say exactly that in your answer, which makes your answer misleading. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406188/does-gcc-really-know-how-to-output-nasm-assembly/8406725#8406725

Comment: Thank you... Are you actually trying to review all NASM related questions on StackOverflow to promote your own answer?

Comment: I actually wondered where the OP got the idea that NASM uses Intel Syntax, so I looked at his questions, and found it out.

Comment: Actually not a problem : ) Good job explaining this to him.

Answer (score 0):

It is at&t assembler. Standard in unix world.