# How to generate assembly code with gcc that can be compiled with nasm

Tags: gcc, assembly, nasm

I am trying to learn assembly language as a hobby and I frequently use `gcc -S` to produce assembly output. This is pretty much straightforward, but I fail to compile the assembly output. I was just curious whether this can be done at all. I tried using both standard assembly output and intel syntax using the `-masm=intel`. Both can't be compiled with `nasm` and linked with `ld`.

Therefore I would like to ask whether it is possible to generate assembly code, that can be then compiled.

To be more precise I used the following C code.

```
 >> cat csimp.c 
 int main (void){
 int i,j;
   for(i=1;i<21;i++)
     j= i + 100;
  return 0;
  }
```

Generated assembly with `gcc -S -O0 -masm=intel  csimp.c` and tried to compile with `nasm -f elf64 csimp.s` and link with `ld -m elf_x86_64 -s -o test csimp.o`. The output I got from nasm reads:

```
csimp.s:1: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
csimp.s:1: error: parser: instruction expected
csimp.s:2: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
csimp.s:2: error: parser: instruction expected
```

This is most probably due to broken assembly syntax. My hope is that I would be able to fix this without having to manually correct the output of `gcc -S`

---

**Edit**:

I was given a [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737947/how-to-generate-a-nasm-compilable-assembly-code-from-c-source-code-on-linux) that my problem is solved in another question; unfortunately, after testing the method described there, I was not able to produce `nasm` assembly format. You can see the output of `objconv` below. 
Therefore I still need your help.

```
>>cat csimp.asm 
; Disassembly of file: csimp.o
; Sat Jan 30 20:17:39 2016
; Mode: 64 bits
; Syntax: YASM/NASM
; Instruction set: 8086, x64

global main:  ; **the ':' should be removed !!!** 


SECTION .text                                           ; section number 1, code

main:   ; Function begin
        push    rbp                                     ; 0000 _ 55
        mov     rbp, rsp                                ; 0001 _ 48: 89. E5
        mov     dword [rbp-4H], 1                       ; 0004 _ C7. 45, FC, 00000001
        jmp     ?_002                                   ; 000B _ EB, 0D

?_001:  mov     eax, dword [rbp-4H]                     ; 000D _ 8B. 45, FC
        add     eax, 100                                ; 0010 _ 83. C0, 64
        mov     dword [rbp-8H], eax                     ; 0013 _ 89. 45, F8
        add     dword [rbp-4H], 1                       ; 0016 _ 83. 45, FC, 01
?_002:  cmp     dword [rbp-4H], 20                      ; 001A _ 83. 7D, FC, 14
        jle     ?_001                                   ; 001E _ 7E, ED
        pop     rbp                                     ; 0020 _ 5D
        ret                                             ; 0021 _ C3
; main End of function


SECTION .data                                           ; section number 2, data


SECTION .bss                                            ; section number 3, bss
```

**Apparent solution:**

I made a mistake when cleaning up the output of `objconv`. I should have run:

```
sed -i "s/align=1//g ; s/[a-z]*execute//g ; s/: *function//g;  /default *rel/d" csimp.asm
```

All steps can be condensed in a `bash` script

```
#! /bin/bash

a=$( echo $1 | sed  "s/\.c//" ) # strip the file extension .c

# compile binary with minimal information
gcc -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -s -c ${a}.c 

# convert the executable to nasm format
./objconv/objconv -fnasm ${a}.o 

# remove unnecesairy objconv information
sed -i "s/align=1//g ; s/[a-z]*execute//g ; s/: *function//g;  /default *rel/d" ${a}.asm

# run nasm for 64-bit binary

nasm -f elf64 ${a}.asm 

# link --> see comment of MichaelPetch below
ld -m elf_x86_64 -s ${a}.o
```

Running this code I get the `ld` warning:

```
 ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000400080
```

The executable produced in this manner crashes with segmentation fault message. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: The output is intended for the gnu assembler (`as`), any particular reason you don't use that? It will "just work". `nasm` has a different syntax, unfortunately.

Comment: I didn't know this. I will try as, thank you for the answer. I am surprised that the assembly syntax is not universal.

Comment: @NateEldredge unfortunately what is written there does not work for me. I guess that `C` assembly conversion is not that straightforward.

Comment: Run `gcc -S -fverbose-asm -O csimp.c`  to get a `csimp.s` assembler file for GNU `as`

Comment: What do you need `nasm` for?

Comment: In your edit, your generated code is 64-bit, but your original question uses `nasm -f elf` and `ld -m elf_i386` (which targets 32-bit). So I'm venturing to guess whatever error you are seeing with the objconv generated code is possible related to you mixing up 32-bit and 64-bit code. So first off, are you trying to create 64-bit code or 32-bit code?  And are you on a 32-bit or 64-bit OS?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you for your comment. I am using both and hence the confusion. I would like to generate `64` bit binary and run it on Suse Linux running `3.16.7-21-desktop` kernel. However, the errors you see are generated by running `nasm`, so the linker is not the problem here. I will correct the error. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Your edit doesn't show how you are compiling and linking that OBJCONV code, but it should be compilable with nasm with something like `nasm -felf64 csimpc.asm` . If you used `nasm -felf csimpc.asm` the `-f elf` tries to generate 32-bit output. You need `-f elf64` if you are trying to assemble 64-bit code. If on a 64-bit system _LD_ will generally output 64-bit executable by default. So you should drop `-m elf_i386` from the LD command or use `ld -m elf_x86_64`. LD with `-m elf_i386` is trying to output to a 32-bit executable

Comment: @MichaelPetch I found the error, I made a mistake when cleaning up the output of `objconv`.

Comment: Instead of editing the answer into the question, you should post the answer as an answer.  Yes, you're allowed to answer your own question.  Also, if you're going to do this, use `gcc -O3`!  The default `-O0` is mostly a literal translation of C into braindead asm.  You might also want `-march=native` or `-mtune=native`, depending on whether you need the code to run on CPUs older than the host, or want it tuned specifically for the host.

Comment: Also, in a bash script, you can just do `a="${1%.c}"` to strip off a trailing `.c`, without having to pipe the string through an external command.  Don't forget to double-quote variables when you expand them, or else your script will break on names with spaces in them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difficulty I think you hit with the *entry point error* was attempting to use `ld` on an object file containing the entry point named `main` while `ld` was looking for an entry point named `_start`.

There are a couple of considerations. First, if you are linking with the C library for the use of functions like `printf`, linking will expect `main` as the entry point, but if you are not linking with the C library, `ld` will expect `_start`. Your script is very close, but you will need some way to differentiate which entry point you need to fully automate the process for any source file.

For example, the following is a conversion using your approach of a source file including `printf`. It was converted to `nasm` using `objconv` as follows:

Generate the object file:

```
gcc -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -s -c struct_offsetof.c -o s3.obj
```

Convert with objconv to *nasm* format assembly file

```
objconv -fnasm s3.obj
```

(note: my version of `objconv` added DOS line endings -- probably an option missed, I just ran it through `dos2unix`)

Using a slightly modified version of your `sed` call, tweak the contents:

```
sed -i -e 's/align=1//g' -e 's/[a-z]*execute//g' -e \
's/: *function//g' -e '/default *rel/d' s3.asm
```

(note: if no standard library functions, and using `ld`, change `main` to `_start` by adding the following expressions to your `sed` call)

```
-e 's/^main/_start/' -e 's/[ ]main[ ]*.*$/ _start/'
```

(there are probably more elegant expressions for this, this was just for example)

Compile with `nasm` (replacing original object file):

```
nasm -felf64 -o s3.obj s3.asm
```

Using `gcc` for link:

```
gcc -o s3 s3.obj
```

Test

```
$ ./s3

 sizeof test : 40

 myint  : 0  0
 mychar : 4  4
 myptr  : 8  8
 myarr  : 16  16
 myuint : 32  32
```

Comment: I changed the `main` to start and the `ld` error disappeared. But the code still produces a `Segmentation fault` error. I have no `printf` in my code, in fact it is just a main and a `for` loop but somehow it still does not run. In general if I would use `gcc` as a linker everything runs smoothly. The problem is compiling with `nasm` and linking with `ld`.

Comment: @AlexanderCska: Of course it segfaults.  It tries to `ret` from `_start`, instead of making an `exit(2)` system call.  `_start` isn't called by anything: it's the real entry point.  The x86-64 ABI specifies that the stack holds argc, *argv, and *envp, not a return address.  It should work if you change your code to call `exit(0)` instead of `return 0`, but then you'd need to link with `libc`.  So you should just link using gcc like David said.  IDK if I missed it, but why are you even doing this?  Are you going to start hand-modifying the asm once you get it to compile and run?

Comment: If you want to use system calls *directly*, without going through the glibc wrapper, there used to be macros like `_syscall1(type, name, type1, arg1)` that would define an inline function to make the system call.  See `_syscall(2)`.  Or you could modify the asm around `call` instructions to put the args in the right registers for a syscall instead of a function call, and use `syscall`.  It clobbers rax, rcx, and r11: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-x86-64

Comment: To call `exit(2)` (aka `sys_exit`): `movq $return_code, %rdi; movq $60, %rax; syscall` or using the old interrupt interface: `movq $1, %rax; mov $rc, %rbx; int $0x80`. This way you won't have to go through libc, but it's also less portable (e.g. AMD uses `sysenter` instead of `syscall`)

Comment: This `sed` command seems to be stripping out NASM `default rel` directives.  That's not a good thing, you want `mov eax, [foo]` to assemble to a RIP-relative addressing mode. Or does objconv use `mov eax, [rel foo]` everywhere as well?

Comment: @PeterCordes - let me run through it. I'll have to find the drive from 2016 to duplicate the versions involved. (luckily, my stack of old SSDs is handy). I don't recall specifically, but I do recall the code failed with `default rel` present. I should have time later tonight.

Comment: That's very weird.  You weren't perhaps using MacOS? Historically NASM has had bugs with the MachO object-file format, including one that broke RIP-relative addressing.  But 32-bit absolute addressing like `mov edx, [abs foo]` isn't possible on MacOS so that wouldn't explain it.  If you're copying linked machine code around at run-time and need it to keep accessing the same absolute address, that would need `abs`, but use-cases are very rare.  Compilers usually only use absolute with no registers for stuff like `mov rax, [rs: 0x28]` (which uses `abs` in current NASM even with `default rel`)

Comment: Also, the regexes could match lines like `defaultrelease:` that define labels for function names that happen to match, since `/ */` can match zero characters.

Comment: That is a good point. Depending on what I find, if the removal is needed I'll make the whitespace specific in the removal with `[[:space:]]`. Chuckling, there has been a bit of water under the bridge since the answer was written, and I can't for the life of me recall the specifics. I do know I'll be able to find the info from this question, a digital pack rat never loses anything `:)`

Answer (score 4):

There are many different assembly languages - for each CPU there's possibly multiple possible syntaxes (e.g. "Intel syntax", "AT&T syntax"), then completely different directives, pre-processor, etc on top of that. It adds up to about 30 different dialects of assembly language for 32-bit 80x86 alone.

GCC is only able to generate one dialect of assembly language for 32-bit 80x86. This means it can't work with NASM, FASM, MASM, TASM, A86/A386, etc. It only works for GAS (and possibly YASM in its "AT&T mode" maybe).

Of course you can compile code with 3 different compilers into 3 different types of assembly, then write 3 more different pieces of code (in 3 more different types of assembly) yourself; then assemble all of that (each with their appropriate assembler) into object files and link all the object files together.

Answer (score 4):

You basically can't, at least directly.  GCC does output assembly in Intel syntax; but NASM/MASM/TASM have their own Intel syntax. They are largely based on it, but there are as well some differences the assembler may not be able to understand and thus fail to compile.

The closest thing is probably having `objdump` show the assembly in Intel format:

```
objdump -d $file -M intel
```

Peter Cordes suggests in the comments that assembler directives will still target GAS, so they won't be recognized by NASM for example. They typically have the same name, but GAS-like directives start with a `.` as in `.section text` (vs `section text`).

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406188/does-gcc-really-know-how-to-output-nasm-assembly?lq=1

Comment: gcc / gas Intel syntax still uses GNU assembler directives like `.align`, `.globl`, while NASM/YASM use directives like `align` and `global`.  So you'd have to port by hand.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, that is true. GCC "limits" itself to telling GAS to switch syntax through another GAS-like directive, `.intel_syntax`.

Comment: But I'm using AMD CPU which command should I execute?