# Replace specific string (after) in file in Python

Tags: python, file, assembly, replace

Replace specific string (below) in file in Python

I have a text file that is something like the following:

```
test   al,al
jne    0x514 <asm4+23>
mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8],0x1
jmp    0x587 <asm4+138>
mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8]
```

I need the result to be like this

```
test   al,al
jne    asm4+23
mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8],0x1
jmp    asm4+138
mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Show your own effort and code to solve the problem as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: What exactly is the difference between the two? What have you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

This could work for your example. I have used python regular expressions

```
import re

regex = r"(0.+<)(.+)>"
input_string="""
test   al,al
jne    0x514 <asm4+23>
mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8],0x1
jmp    0x587 <asm4+138>
mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8]

"""
output=re.sub(r"(0.+<)(.+)>", r"\2", input_string)
print(output)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use just ".startswith" method:

```
test = """
    test   al,al
    jne    0x514 <asm4+23>
    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8],0x1
    jmp    0x587 <asm4+138>
    mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8]
    """.splitlines()

i = 0
while i < len(test):
    if test[i].startswith("jne"):
        test[i] = "jne    0x514 <asm4+23>"
    elif test[i].startswith("jmp"):
        test[i] = "jmp    0x587 <asm4+138>"
    i += 1

print("\n".join(test))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're converting disassembly into something that can be re-assembled.

Instead of post-processing GDB or `objdump -drwC -Mintel` output, use a disassembler that outputs in actual GAS or NASM syntax in the first place, with extra info in comments.  Specifically for x86, [Agner Fog's `objconv`](https://www.agner.org/optimize/#objconv).

See [How to generate assembly code with gcc that can be compiled with nasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102193/how-to-generate-assembly-code-with-gcc-that-can-be-compiled-with-nasm) for example output.

(I don't think it can target GAS `.intel_syntax`, only GAS, NASM/YASM, or MASM.  But GAS `.intel_syntax` is MASM-like except for the directives so that may be useful.  Or if you don't mind AT&T syntax, it can be assembled directly without installing NASM.)