# Difference between GAS and NASM syntaxes in loading a global variable using RIP-relative addressing mode

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, nasm, gnu-assembler

What is the proper **NASM** equivalent of the following two functions?

```
get_user_input:  ; (char*, unsigned long)
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     qword [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     qword [rbp-16], rsi
        mov     rdx, qword stdin[rip]  ; previously: mov   rdx, QWORD PTR stdin[rip]
        mov     rax, qword [rbp-16]
        mov     ecx, eax
        mov     rax, qword [rbp-8]
        mov     esi, ecx
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    fgets
        nop
        leave
        ret

print_string:  ; (char const*)
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     qword [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     rdx, qword stdout[rip]  ; previously: mov   rdx, QWORD PTR stdout[rip]
        mov     rax, qword [rbp-8]
        mov     rsi, rdx
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    fputs
        nop
        leave
        ret
```

The above snippet was originally in *GAS* syntax and I manually converted it to *NASM*. It was generated using GCC (`-O0`) from the following C++ code:

```cpp
void
get_user_input( char* const buffer, const std::size_t buffer_size ) noexcept
{
    std::fgets( buffer, static_cast<int>( buffer_size ), stdin );
}

void
print_string( const char* const str ) noexcept
{
    std::fputs( str, stdout );
}
```

But my conversion was not without errors. Apparently, the external symbols must be declared at the top of the file:

```
extern fgets
extern fputs
extern stdin
extern stdout
```

This solves some issues. But NASM says there are still issues in these two lines:

```
        mov     rdx, qword stdin[rip]
```

and

```
        mov     rdx, qword stdout[rip]
```

The error message:

```
nasm -g -F dwarf -f elf64 Main.asm -l Main.lst -o Main.o
Main.asm:96: error: symbol `rip' not defined
Main.asm:111: error: symbol `rip' not defined
```

How do we tell NASM to move the address of `stdout` or `stdin` to the `rdx` register similar to the above GAS assembly code?

Comment: nasm uses the `rel` keyword for rip relative addressing. Try `mov rdx, [rel stdin]`.

Comment: @Jester This worked. Thanks. I still don't quite understand what it loads to the register though.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate of [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427) but my answer there does mention NASM's `default rel` , and links [How do RIP-relative variable references like "\[RIP + \_a\]" in x86-64 GAS Intel-syntax work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54745872) which shows the NASM alternative `[rel + stdout]`.  That's maybe closer to a duplicate since the problem is trying to use GAS's syntax in NASM.

Comment: [Why use RIP-relative addressing in NASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36952302) shows examples of NASM RIP-relative addressing, mostly in the context of LEA but also one MOV load.  IIRC there's also a Q&A somewhere about translating GAS to NASM; assembling with GAS and disassembling with Agner Fog's `objconv` into NASM syntax should work to get the instruction syntax right.  (Also, compile with at least `-Og` for trivial functions like this where the debug-mode stack frame stuff is not useful.)

Comment: It loads the content of `stdin`. It's functionally equivalent to `mov rdx, [stdin]` but it uses a position independent addressing mode.

Comment: [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34058101) shows NASM `[rel foo]` and mentions `default rel` at once point, but not a great duplicate.  [How to generate assembly code with gcc that can be compiled with nasm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35102193) basically just suggests `objconv` and does some wonky and ill-advised processing like changing `main` to `_start`, but `_start` isn't a function.

Comment: @Jester So does that interfere with `-no-pie` linker option?

Comment: Oops, typo on my earlier comment.  `[rel stdin]` not `[rel + stdin]`.  Re: `-no-pie`: You can always use RIP-relative addressing, even if it's not required.  It's more efficient for loads/stores, only useful to use absolute addressing like `mov edi, format_string` or something in a non-PIE, or `mov eax, [global_array + rdx*4]`, which rely on 32-bit absolute addressing.  See [Why does this MOVSS instruction use RIP-relative addressing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44967075) and [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427)

Comment: The `-no-pie` relaxes the requirements so you don't have to use rip relative but you may still do so.

Comment: @Jester Makes sense. I guess I'll keep it that way.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think you could as well turn your comment into an answer. Would be better for others viewing this question later.

Comment: The main reason I didn't want to answer this question is that the title isn't the real issue, it's how to load a global variable in x86-64 NASM syntax.  Or how to write a RIP-relative addressing mode in NASM.  Those are useful canonical questions to have for future readers to find.  The fputs stuff is just the context (or a separate question about why `FILE *stdin` needs a load?).  A title about translating from GAS `.intel_syntax noprefix` to NASM for x86-64 could also work, since the previous questions about that topic didn't mention the RIP-relative addressing mode syntax difference.

Comment: I notice you said the asm was output by GCC, but nowhere did you mention changing `qword ptr` to `qword`.  That's necessary (or just remove the size override when implied by the other operand), but it would be better to show the actual original GCC output of `mov     rdx, qword ptr stdin[rip]` as well as your attempt at porting it to NASM.

Comment: @PeterCordes The new title should make more sense now.

Comment: @PeterCordes I only changed `QWORD PTR` to `qword`. The rest of it was left intact.

Comment: I know, since I know what GCC output looks like.  I meant to make it a better question for future readers to find by searching, like if they searched on "qword ptr" "rip" or something.  I realized after posting the comment that the variable name comes in between the `qword ptr` and the `rip`, so an exact string match from a search engine isn't going to easily find it. So at least to make the question make sense to other total beginners who wouldn't realize you took out a `PTR` if you don't say so, and they wonder why their GCC output doesn't look like that.

Comment: I guess one way to formulate this into a useful question would be what else do you have to do to translate GAS Intel-syntax addressing modes to NASM, beyond taking out `ptr` everywhere.  (Your current title is good, too, focusing on RIP-relative.)  I'll probably post an answer sometime if you or someone else doesn't answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have added the previous GAS code where needed. You might want to write an answer.