# Compile intel assembly with gcc/mingw

Tags: gcc, assembly

I want to compile intel syntax assembly using gcc. Is it possible? because I cant find something similar. I've only found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199966/how-do-you-use-gcc-to-generate-assembly-code-in-intel-syntax).

Here is the code I am trying to compile.

```
    global  _main
    section .text
_main:
    mov eax, -1     
        ret
```

If this is not possible please provide alternative options in your answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding a `.intel_syntax` directive works for me:

```
  .globl _main
  .intel_syntax

_main:
  mov eax, -1     
  ret
```

Assembling and running:

```
$ gcc -o example example.s; ./example; echo $?
255
```

Comment: Works for me too. Where did you find that?

Comment: I did a Google search for "gcc intel syntax".  It was either the first or second hit.

Comment: gcc version 4.4.0 (GCC), which one you have?

Comment: Actually it forces you to have .s file extension to your file. That's why it didn't work.

Comment: Hi guys, I've got this working, but the comments in my code (starting with ';' have not been removed. Is there a solution to this?)

Comment: @EdwardBird, I think intel-syntax comments start with a `#`.

Comment: @CarlNorum Oh, okay thanks... Why did I seem to think they began with ';' ? Is that an AT&T thing?

Comment: By the way, for anyone wondering I managed to get it to work by compiling with nasm first, and then linking using gcc instead of ld... Since I defined main not `_start`