# GCC Generated ASM simplified x86 ASM? How to map?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86

When I compile the following code to asm in GCC on cygwin:

```
int scheme_entry() {
  return 42;
}
```

using:

```
gcc -O3 --omit-frame-pointer -S test1.c
```

I get the following 'ASM' generated:

```
    .file   "test1.c"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
.globl _scheme_entry
    .def    _scheme_entry;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_scheme_entry:
    movl    $42, %eax
    ret
```

But the 'MOVL' command isn't actually x86 ASM. From looking at the following lists:

http://ref.x86asm.net/geek.html#x0FA0

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings

There is no MOVL command, but there is

```
CMOVL
CMOVLE
MOVLPS
MOVLPD
MOVLHPS
```

My question is - is gcc ASM "simplified ASM"? If so - how do I map it to 'real ASM'?

Comment: AT&T syntax should be shot in the head. I don't know why anyone uses it

Comment: @James I prefer AT&T syntax because I find it cleaner and easier to read. It also flows better since the source operand comes first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by ughoavgfhw, GCC outputs AT&T syntax by default, which is different to the Intel-style syntax you seem to be expecting. This behaviour, however, is configurable: you can request it to output Intel-style as follows:

```
gcc -masm=intel -O3 --omit-frame-pointer -S test1.c
```

with the key parameter being `-masm=intel`.

Using this command line, the assembly output I get (with a few unnecessary lines cut out for brevity) is as follows:

```
scheme_entry:
    mov eax, 42
    ret
```

Answer (score 3):

GCC uses AT&T syntax. One of the differences is that operand sizes can be specified using an instruction suffix, and the compiler will always use these suffixes. This is actually a `mov` instruction with an `l` suffix, which means a 32-bit operand size.

Comment: Ah! So you're hinting that I should be doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199966/how-do-you-use-gcc-to-generate-assembly-code-in-intel-syntax