# How to generate assembly code with clang in Intel syntax?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, clang, intel

As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199966/how-do-you-use-gcc-to-generate-assembly-code-in-intel-syntax) shows, with g++, I can do `g++ -S -masm=intel test.cpp`.
Also, with clang, I can do `clang++ -S test.cpp`, but `-masm=intel` is not supported by clang (`warning argument unused during compilation: -masm=intel`). How do I get intel syntax with clang?

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Thanks, I generated a `.bc` file with clang and then sucessfully output the Intel assembly with `llc`. Mind making that an answer?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

As [noted below by @thakis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23630416/1172350), newer versions of Clang (3.5+) accept the `-masm=intel` argument.

---

For older versions, this should get clang to emit assembly code with Intel syntax:

```
clang++ -S -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel test.cpp
```

You can use `-mllvm <arg>` to pass in llvm options from the clang command line. Sadly this option doesn't appear to be well documented, and thus I only found it by browsing through the llvm mailing lists.

Comment: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17465 requests support for -masm=intel and beyond.

Comment: @dcoles Not working for clang 3.7. I executed `$clang  -S -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel file.c`. Am I doint something wrong here? It's not giving any error and silently exiting.

Comment: @saumya-suhagiya I've just confirmed that this still works with clang 3.8.0-svn244195-1~exp1. The command shown above will generate a file called `test.s`. You change this output location to a custom location using the `-o <path>` option.

Comment: @dcoles Hi, perhaps a not so smart question. Is it possible to compile and link the assembly code with `nasm`?

Comment: @AlexanderCska I'm not sure this is possible without some manual fixup. While the syntax for NASM is similar to Intel's, there is some incompatibilities between them.

Answer (score 51):

As of clang [r208683](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20140512/105330.html) (clang 3.5+), it understands `-masm=intel`. So if your clang is new enough, you can just use that.

Comment: It seems to me that the code generated by `-masm=intel` cannot be compiled by `clang` again? I am running clang 3.8.

Answer (score 17):

Presuming you can have Clang emit normal LLVM byte codes, you can then use [llc](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llc.html) to compile to assembly language, and use its `--x86-asm-syntax=intel` option to get the result in Intel syntax.

Comment: Thanks again. I also found out `llc` by default turns optimizations on (-02) while gcc and clang use no optimizations (-O0) by default (it took me forever to figure out why the assembly output was different).