# Inline assembly with intel syntax using LLVM: Unknown token in expression

Tags: c, llvm, inline-assembly

When compiling this code with Apple LLVM 4.1 in Xcode I get an error:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int a = 1;
    printf("a = %d\n", a);

    asm volatile(".intel_syntax noprefix;"
        "mov [%0], 2;"
        :
        : "r" (&a)
        );

    printf("a = %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

The error is `Unknown token in expression`.

If I use AT&T syntax it works fine:

```
asm volatile("movl $0x2, (%0);"
                 :
                 : "r" (&a)
                 : "memory"
                 );
```

What is wrong with the first code?

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990018/how-to-generate-assembly-code-with-clang-in-intel-syntax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the compiler is translating `%0` to `%reg` (`%rcx` on my machine) and the assembler does not like the `%` (as it is in intel mode).

I don't know if it's possible to mix the automatic register allocation feature ([extended asm](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html)) with the intel syntax, as I've not seen any example yet.

Good documentation about gcc inline assembly is usually hard to come by, and clang states in its [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#inline-asm) that it's mostly compatible with gcc in this area...