# Trying to grasp C bytecode... does/can GNU/gcc produce C bytecode like Clang/LLVM?

Tags: c, gcc, llvm, clang, bytecode

Recently I was told to look at how C functions are compiled into LLVM bytecode, and then how the LLVM bytecode is translated into x86 ASM. As a regular GNU/gcc user, I have some questions about this. To put it mildly.

Does GNU/gcc compile to bytecode, too? *Can it?* I was under the impression that gcc compiles directly into ASM. If not, is there a way to view the bytecode intermediary as there is with the clang command?

`~$ clang ~/prog_name.c -S -emit-llvm -o -` <== will show bytecode for prog_name.c.

Also, I find bytecode to be rather byzantine. By contrast, it makes assembly language seem like light reading. In other words: I have little idea what it is saying.

*Does anyone have any advice or references for vaguely deciphering the information that the bytecode gives?* Currently I compare and contrast with actual ASM, so to say it is slow going is a compliment.

Perhaps this is all comically naive, but I find it quite challenging to break through the surface of this.

Comment: http://llvm.org/releases/1.3/docs/CommandGuide/html/llvmgcc.html

Comment: And for the docs on LLVM language itself: http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html

Comment: @RobertHarvey that looks significantly more helpful than http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html ... thank you

Comment: @RobertHarvey: note that you're linking to a *very* old release of LLVM. llvmgcc has long been deprecated. Its functionality is now implemented via the dragonegg gcc plugin.

Comment: @EliBendersky: Thanks.  I did notice that it was quite old.

Comment: Perhaps the source of your confusion is the term "C bytecode" - there is no such thing. The LLVM intermediate representation (called "LLVM bitcode" or "LLVM IR") is an [SSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) programming language which is not related to C. GCC uses another intermediate representation (actually, multiple ones) which is not related to C either.

Comment: Try running `gcc -fdump-tree-ssa`

Comment: @SK-logic How to examine the dump? I checked the manual and ran `gcc -fdump-tree-ssa program.c -o program.ssa` but `nano program.ssa` looks like wingdings... or is that how it is supposed to look?

Comment: @d0rmLife, you're looking at a binary file. You have to examine the file with a name like 'program.c.????.ssa', it should be generated in the same directory where your `program.c` is.

Comment: @SK-logic Nice. That looks better :P

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps try taking a look at the [language reference](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html).

As far as I know, GCC does have an IR as well known as [GIMPLE](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GIMPLE) (another [reference here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html)).

If you mean that you would rather analyze the assembly output instead of the IR, you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990018/how-to-generate-assembly-code-with-clang-in-intel-syntax) which describes how to output an assembly file.

Comment: @d0rmLife Indeed I believe the gcc site is down temporarily, I linked them anyways because they are the links you'll want to see (aka official etc.)