# Why does GCC generate a faster program than Clang in this recursive Fibonacci code?

Tags: c++, gcc, x86, clang, compiler-optimization

This is the code that I tested:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

#define CHRONO_NOW                  chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()
#define CHRONO_DURATION(first,last) chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(last-first).count()

int fib(int n) {
    if (n<2) return n;
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}

int main() {
    auto t0 = CHRONO_NOW;
    cout << fib(45) << endl;
    cout << CHRONO_DURATION(t0, CHRONO_NOW) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, there are much faster ways of calculating Fibonacci numbers, but this is a good little stress test that focuses on recursive function calls.
There's nothing else to the code, other than the use of chrono for measuring time.

First I ran the test a couple of times in Xcode on OS X (so that's clang), using `-O3` optimization. It took about 9 seconds to run.

Then, I compiled the same code with gcc (g++) on Ubuntu (using -O3 again), and that version only took about 6.3 seconds to run! Also, I was running Ubuntu **inside VirtualBox** on my mac, which could only affect the performance negatively, if at all.

So there you go:

- Clang on OS X -> ~9 secs
- gcc on Ubuntu **in VirtualBox** -> ~6.3 secs.

I know that these are completely different compilers so they do stuff differently, but all the tests I've seen featuring gcc and clang only showed much less of a difference, and in some cases, the difference was the other way around (clang being faster).

So is there any logical explanation why gcc beats clang by miles in this particular example?

Comment: Did you check the assembly output? And what's the version of Clang and gcc?

Comment: Don't use these defines. That's what the `using` directive is for: `using chrono_time_point = chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point;`

Comment: look at the code generated, it's a simple function

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc gcc is 4.9.1, and clang is whatever version the latest Xcode includes, I didn't check. How do I check the assembly output?

Comment: @Cubic What's the reason behind that?

Comment: Try `constexpr int fibonacci(int n) { return n<2 ? n : fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2); }`

Comment: The reason is that you want to avoid 'leaving the language' as much as possible. But that's exactly what you're doing with preprocessor directives.  One obvious consequence is that error messages become less useful (giving you the preprocessor resolved name instead of your alias).

Comment: @imallett It's about the same.

Comment: this is silly. the answer is : "because they are different compilers, because different optimizations are enabled".

Comment: Aah, I get it now. I tried both with no optimization flags, and the results were very close this time. The clang version took ~9.5 secs, and gcc took ~10.5. So I guess -O3 makes gcc more likely to inline function calls, while clang with -O3 doesn't do that in this case.

Comment: The answer to this question is likely to ephemeral, as both compilers will continue to evolve and improve.

Comment: To get the assembly output: [Using GCC to produce readable assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1289881/995714), [How do you get assembler output from C/C++ source in gcc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/137038/995714), [How to generate assembly code with clang in Intel syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10990018/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't say that gcc beats clang by miles. In my opinion, the performance difference (6.3 seconds vs 9 seconds) is rather small. On my FreeBSD system, clang requires 26.12 seconds and gcc requires 10.55 seconds.

However, the way to debug this is to use `g++ -S` and `clang++ -S` to get the assembly output.

I tested this on my FreeBSD system. The assembly language files are too long to post here, but it appears that gcc performs multiple levels of inlining in the Fibonacci calculation function (there were 20 `fib()` calls in there!) whereas clang simply calls `fib(n-1)` and `fib(n-2)` with no levels of inlining.

By the way, my gcc version was 4.2.1 20070831 patched [FreeBSD] and clang version was 3.1 (branches/release_31 156863) 20120523. These were the versions that come with the FreeBSD 9.1-RELEAESE base system. The CPU is AMD Turion II Neo N40L Dual-Core Processor (1497.54-MHz).

Comment: So basically it comes down to inlining, at least to a certain amount of "depth". Interesting...

Comment: A factor 1.4 isn't small, that's huge.

Answer (score 12):

GCC 4.9.2 in [compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) really does loop-unrolling and inlines a lot of function calls while Clang 3.5.1 calls `fib` ***twice* each iteration** without even [tail call optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/310974/995714) like below

```
fib(int):                                # @fib(int)
        push    rbp
        push    rbx
        push    rax
        mov     ebx, edi
        cmp     ebx, 2
        jge     .LBB0_1
        mov     eax, ebx
        jmp     .LBB0_3
.LBB0_1:
        lea     edi, dword ptr [rbx - 1]
        call    fib(int)       # fib(ebx - 1)
        mov     ebp, eax
        add     ebx, -2
        mov     edi, ebx
        call    fib(int)       # fib(ebx - 2)
        add     eax, ebp
.LBB0_3:
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

The GCC version is more than 10 times longer, with **only a single `fib` call and 20+ labels for inlining the call**, which also means that the last call has been tail-optimized into a `jmp` or GCC has converted some of the recursion into iteration (since it allocates a big array for storing intermediate values)

I've also brought ICC into perspective, and surprisingly it has 10 `call` instructions inside `fib`, and it also **inlines `fib` calls 9 times inside `main`**, but it doesn't convert the recursive code to iterative

[Here's the compiler outputs for comparison](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cchrono%3E%0Ausing+namespace+std%3B%0A%0A%23define+CHRONO_NOW++++++++++++++++++chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()%0A%23define+CHRONO_DURATION(first,last)+chrono::duration_cast%3Cchrono::duration%3Cdouble%3E%3E(last-first).count()%0A%0Aint+fib(int+n)+%7B%0A++++if+(n%3C2)+return+n%3B%0A++++int+t+%3D+fib(n-1)%3B%0A++++return+t+%2B+fib(n-2)%3B%0A++++//+or+return+fib(n-1)+%2B+fib(n-2)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++auto+t0+%3D+CHRONO_NOW%3B%0A++++cout+%3C%3C+fib(45)+%3C%3C+endl%3B%0A++++cout+%3C%3C+CHRONO_DURATION(t0,+CHRONO_NOW)+%3C%3C+endl%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:28.282168517308946,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g492,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B0x+-O3+-fverbose-asm',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+4.9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0'),(h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang351,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B0x+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+3.5.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0'),(h:compiler,i:(compiler:icc19,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B0x+-O3+-fverbose-asm',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+icc+19.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:71.71783148269105,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Note that you can modify the code like this to make the output easier to read

```
int fib(int n) {
    if (n<2) return n;
    int t = fib(n-1);
    return t + fib(n-2);
}
```

Now *compiler explorer* will highlight which source code line an instruction in the assembly output corresponds to with distinct colors, and you'll easily see how the two calls are made. The line `return t + fib(n-2)` is compiled by GCC to

```
.L3:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+112]  # n, %sfp
        add     edx, DWORD PTR [rsp+64]   # D.35656, %sfp
        add     DWORD PTR [rsp+60], edx   # %sfp, D.35656
        sub     DWORD PTR [rsp+104], 2    # %sfp,
```