# How can i produce an object file from an assembler source in the same way as clang -c main.c does

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

I want to study the detail of an `obj` file, I have produced an `main.S` file, when I use `as main.S` I get an `a.out` file in return which can be run directly with `./a.out` and `ld -m elf_x86_64 a.out` would  produce an error.

I want to produce an object file of which the file type is the same with the result of `clang -c main.c`.
How can I do that?

---

I may have mix up the operation, which resulting a wrong interpretation. **`as` does not produce an executable, the executable is result of clang.** thank you to all answerers, I am very sorry to cause confusion, and have wasted your time.

Comment: What have you done to assemble the object file?  You can do `cc -c main.S` to get such an object file.  Or use `clang` or any other compiler instead of `cc`.

Comment: I am trying to manipulate the middle result to see what would came out as a final result to learn reverse engineering.

Comment: @Riu Your question is correctly phrased "I want to produce an object file of which the file type is the same with the result of clang -c main.c". And you tried to link the resultant object file with `ld`, so it doesn't seem that you have misunderstood preproc/asm/COFF/linking stages in the executable build process ^^

Comment: @Riu I suggest you to rephrase your question title with something more accurate with your intent like "How can i produce an object file from an assembler source in the same way as clang -c main.c does"

Comment: Thank you @zilog80, I have changed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`as -o foo.o  foo.s`**

If you have a `.S`, normally that means you want to run it through the C preprocessor before assembling.  The `gcc` and `clang` front-ends will do that for you: `gcc -c foo.S` (default output filename foo.o, instead of a.out).  If your `.S` doesn't actually have any CPP directives like `#if` or `#define`, though, you can just assemble it with `as`.

---

`a.out` is the default name for the output of `as`, but it *is* an object file like you'd get from `gcc -c foo.s`, not a linked executable!  **GNU Binutils `as` does not produce linked executables.**

(The default output filename for `ld foo.o` or `gcc` / `clang` without `-c` is *also* a.out, but don't be fooled by the name.)

You can use `gcc -v -c foo.s` to show the `as` command line it uses, including the `-o` option.  (clang has a built-in assembler, so it won't run a separate `as` command, but the `gcc` front-end truly does just run `as` to assemble asm source files.  And without `-c`, then runs `ld` (via collect2) to link the object file into an executable.)

e.g. on my x86-64 GNU/Linux system:

```
$ cat > foo.s
mov $231, %eax             # __NR_exit_group
syscall
$ as foo.s
$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
$ ld a.out -o exit
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000401000
$ ls -l exit a.out 
-rw-r--r-- 1 peter peter  664 Mar 22 08:23 a.out
-rwxr-xr-x 1 peter peter 4632 Mar 22 08:23 exit
$ file exit
exit: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped

$ ./a.out
bash: ./a.out: Permission denied
$ ./exit
$ strace ./exit 
execve("./exit", ["./exit"], 0x7ffc72823fc0 /* 55 vars */) = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

```
$ as --version
GNU assembler (GNU Binutils) 2.35.1
...
This assembler was configured for a target of `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'.
$ ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.35.1
...
```

Comment: I assumed it's a linked file because the result file `a.out` is runnable using `./a.out`.

Comment: @Rui: Like I demonstrated, on my Arch GNU/Linux system, that is *not* the case.  It doesn't have exec permission, and it's an ELF "relocatable" not "executable" or "shared object"/"PIE executable".  Even if I chmod it, I get `Exec format error` on trying to run it.  What kind of system are you on?

Comment: I see `relocatable` in `file a.out` too, but in my case its runnable. I am at ubuntu. Is it because the format relocatable and executable are so close that sometimes relocatable are also runnable?

Comment: @Rui: They're both ELF, but a relocatable is not runnable by any mechanism I'm aware of: it hasn't been linked yet so it isn't ready to run.  Only thing I can think of is some kind of `binfmt_misc` setup that transparently links it into an executable on the fly.

Comment: @Rui: Are you *sure* you're not accidentally running some other `a.out` that is a linked executable?  Does `readelf -a a.out` show any "program headers"?  ELF Program Headers are what's necessary for the kernel's program-loader to map it into virtual address space of a process.  In my a.out, I see `There are no program headers in this file.`  (Only section headers; that's why it works as linker input.)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't remember the exact result of `file a.out`, it's an executable. `gcc -v -c hello.s` helped me find out `as --64 -o hello.o hello.s` is the result. I have doubt checked the result,  I am sure this answer is right. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Oh, you are totally right, I have mixed up the result!!!!I am very sorry. `as` does not produce executable file!!!

Comment: @Rui: The `as` defaults are `--64 -o a.out`, so GCC is just being explicit about it, and setting a different output filename.  If you had an executable, not relocatable, a.out, it was probably left over from running `gcc hello.s` (without `-c`), or from running `ld a.out` which reads `a.out` (an object file) and writes a new `a.out` (an executable).  (Except that doesn't work because `ld a.out` truncates a.out before it reads it, so you get an "executable" with no .text)

Comment: Note that OP's file is named `main.S`, so the preprocessor might need to run.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way, use `clang -v -fno-integrated-as -c main.c` and get the gas command line from its output.

Comment: It shows clang's command line, I don't see a command line start with `as`.

Comment: @Rui: This would only work with `gcc -v -c foo.s` (or foo.c), not clang.  clang has a built-in assembler so it doesn't need to run `as` on it.

Comment: If you've llvm clang, you can tell it to not use its integrated AS with `-fno-integrated-as`. By default, LLVM uses its proper integrated  assembler.

Comment: @Zilog80: The OP is looking for a command to assemble a `.s` into a `.o`.  So `clang -S` is the answer to a different question.  `clang -c foo.s` is a valid answer (given clang's built-in assembler, it works on its own without having to fork off an `as`).

Comment: @Peter Cordes The `clang -S` here is to show a way to get an assembler source from the C source with syntax choice. But it's true that the -llvm isn't directly related to the question, i'll remove my edit.

Comment: Yes, I know what `-S` does, that's how I know it's not an answer to the question "how to assemble an existing `.s`".  Yeah, it's a useful related thing, which you could leave in your answer if you explain exactly what it does, although that's covered by Q&As like [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) and [How to generate assembly code with clang in Intel syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10990018)

Comment: @PeterCordes As it's already covered in other Q&As, -llvm was then just noise in the answer.

Comment: A good solution.  `no-integrated-as` is a bit hard to find in the sea of options clang offered.