# Trying to convert at&t to nasm

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86, nasm

I'm new to `at&t` syntax. I compiled a test.c file with `gcc -S test.c`.

part of file in test.s:

```
 1. .file "test.c"
 2. .local temp
 3. .comm temp,8,4
 4. ...
 5. funtion1:
 6. blah
 7. blah
 8. blah
 9. movl $temp, -8(%ebp)
```

I know `-8(%ebp)` is a local var,but not sure what `$temp` means

How can this be done in nasm?

I have a global temp in the .bss section

can i say:

1. `mov eax, [ebp-8]`; Does eax contains the memory address of [ebp-8]?
2. `mov ebx, temp`; Does ebx contain the address of temp?
3. `mov [eax], ebx`; Does this mean make the local variable point to temp, or that it makes a copy of temp in the local variable?

Comment: To rather indirectly answer your question, why not have [gcc output Intel syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199966/how-do-you-use-gcc-to-generate-assembly-code-in-intel-syntax)?

Comment: I hve a question. did what you say.. yay and looks good. What does the PTR mean in "mov edx, DWORD PTR [eax]", Because it is everywhere

Comment: Can it be just omitted? @A. Webb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`movl $temp, -8(%ebp)` writes the address of your `temp` into the local variable at `ebp-8`
This can be done in nasm as `mov dword [ebp-8], temp`

To answer your other questions:

1. no, `eax` contains the value of the local variable at `[ebp-8]`. To load the address, you can use `lea eax, [ebp-8]`
2. yes
3. makes the local variable a pointer to `temp`, if `eax` holds the address of the local variable (see point #1).

Comment: thanks alot Jester :) mov dword [ebp-8], temp, this helped me alot

Answer (score 0):

To convert into normal x86 syntax:
1. Remove the % from in front of the registers: movl $LC0, (%esp) => movl $LC0, (esp)
2. Remove the $ from in front of constants: movl $LC0, (esp) => movl LC0, (esp)
3. Change () to []: movl LC0, (esp) => movl LC0, [esp]
4. Reverse the order of operands: movl LC0, [esp] => movl [esp], LC0
5. Convert instruction size suffixes into prefixes: mov [esp], dword LC0.

I found the answer here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/lounge/88169/