# How to generate Intel assembler syntax from ghc of haskell?

Tags: haskell, assembly, compiler-construction, ghc

I know there is a -S flag in ghc in haskell, 
and it generates a .s file which is an assembling file.

I am wondering whether GHC is possible to generate the assembler file with Intel syntax?
THank you!!

Comment: Which backend are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 8.

Comment: The backend, not the OS: -fasm, -fllvm, something else.. If you're using -fllvm at least, you can make it switch to Intel syntax by passing --x86-asm-syntax=intel to llvm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's based on GCC, it might support the `-masm=intel` flag. See [How do you use gcc to generate assembly code in Intel syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/199966/422797)

A less nice option is to use `objdump` on the compiled file:

`objdump -d --disassembler-options=intel file.o`

Comment: `ghc: unrecognised flags: -masm=intel`, GHC doesn't speak intel, so it seems `objdump` (or another disassembler) is the only way.

Comment: Alternatively, there seems to be a few tools around for converting between the different assembly formats. You may have some luck with those.