# OS X - undefined symbols for architecture i386 when using inline assembly in C

Tags: c, assembly, i386

I'm trying to compile code containing the following function:

```
void print_stacktrace()
{
    void *addr;
    asm("mov %0, esp;" : "=r" (addr));
}
```

As you can see there is some inline i386 assembly involved. The problem is, when trying to run:

```
clang -masm=intel -m32 test.c -o test
```

The compiler outputs:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "esp", referenced from:
      _print_stacktrace in test-093116.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang-3.9: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

However the code compiles fine on x64 Ubuntu, so it seems problem is OS X specific. How to get this working? I can't believe Apple didn't supply i386 symbols in Xcode Developer tools package (which I have), so maybe something is misconfigured here... Any ideas?

EDIT: So it seems intel syntax is not supported on OS X by default. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: What arch your OSX is running on? Probably not i386 compatible...

Comment: If the assembly is using AT&T syntax, then it should be `mov %esp, %0`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's x64 MacBook Air, but I have no problems with compiling and running 32-bit C executables, so it seems it is i386 compatible...

Comment: @user3078414 use `-masm=intel` flag too, to make sure it understands code inside `asm` (it's intel syntax).

Comment: Here's the result @qiubit: `error: bad value (intel) for -masm= switch`

Comment: @user3078414 what's your version of clang? It seems -masm flag is supported in clang 3.5+. Try to use `-mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel` instead.

Comment: I attempted to build it with gcc, @qiubit. Yet man gcc says `masm=dialect… …intel not supported in Darwin`

Comment: Can you show us the output for `gcc -v` (version info)

Comment: gcc is alias for clang on my OSX (this is default I guess)

Comment: I suspect the gcc in macports or homebrew might support Intel syntax

Comment: Since you already depend on `gcc`/`clang`, why not use the `__builtin_return_address()`? Also glibc has `backtrace()`, not sure if that's available on OSX.

Comment: @Jester that's an educational excercise I'm doing, I'm aware of `backtrace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that `-masm=intel` isn't or wasn't supported in OSX default *Developer Tools* installation, according to `man gcc`,  at least in the versions I'm currently using: 
`gcc --version`
`i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)`
The code, slightly modified, compiles and runs on OSX 10.7.x.
 
`> gcc -m32 -masm=att -o test1 test1.c`

In a newer version of OSX (10.10.x) `gcc` seems aliased to `clang`. `-masm=intel` also doesn't seem supported:
`> clang --version`
`Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.56) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)`
`Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0`
`Thread model: posix`
`> clang -m32 -o test1 test1.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>

void* print_stacktrace()
{
    void *addr;
    asm("mov %%esp, %0;" : "=r" (addr));
    return addr;
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%p\n", print_stacktrace());
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this can help. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199966/how-do-you-use-gcc-to-generate-assembly-code-in-intel-syntax) may also be of relevance.

Comment: No need to use `-masm=att` as [ATT syntax](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax) is the default for _GCC_

Comment: That's a good answer, but I'm wondering if there's any way of enabling intel syntax on OS X.

Comment: You probably can't enable what isn't there. Just try ` -masm=intel` and see what you'll get. Also read the manual. Yet, there is a chance, as @Michael Petch stated in his comment, that a _macports_ or _homebrew_ versions of gcc may support `intel` syntax. Probably some commercial compilers such as `intel` C compiler also do.

Comment: Please, also take a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199966/how-do-you-use-gcc-to-generate-assembly-code-in-intel-syntax).

Comment: OK it seems clang doesn't support intel syntax (bug?) and gcc doesn't support intel syntax on Darwin, so it seems there is no simple way to enable that...