# Porting yasm code (Intel style) to gas (AT&T style)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler, yasm

I'm trying to learn about strings in assembly x86 32bit but recently switched from yasm to gas and tried translating the sources file btw I used xorpd code you can see [here](https://github.com/xorpd/asm_prog_ex_yasm)
I saw some AT&T syntax and I tried translating [include file](https://github.com/xorpd/asm_prog_ex_yasm/blob/master/include/training.s) but However I failed to translate it I don't know where is the problem and if someone can tell me where is the problem in my code.

> strings.s

```
.include 'fn.s'

.extern exit

ARRLEN = 5 /* equivalent to .set ARRLEN, 0x5 */

.data /* data section equivalent to .section .data */

    saar: .long 3,5,8 /* array of 32bit integers */
    daar: .fill ARRLEN, 4, 0 /* array of 32bit integers 4 bytes is size it's in format of
.fill repeat, size, value

i used it to intialize the array ARRLEN times with value 0*/

.text /* text section equivalent to .section .text */

.globl _start /* for ld compatibility reasons. equivalent to .global main */

_start:
    movl  ARRLEN, %ecx
    movl  $saar, %esi
    xor   %eax, %eax

_par:
    call  read_hex
    stosl
    loop  _par

    push  $0
    call  exit
```

> fn.s

```
.data 

hex_new:  .asciz "%x\n"
hex_:     .asciz "%x"
dec_:     .asciz "%d"
dec_new:  .asciz "%d\n"
str_:     .asciz "%s"
new_:     .asciz "\n"
delim:    .asciz "========\n"

.text

print_eax:
    pushal
    push    %eax
    push    $hex_new
    call    printf
    add     $8, %esp
    popal
    ret

print_eax_dec:
    pushal
    push    %eax
    push    $dec_new
    call    printf
    add     $8, %esp
    popal
    ret

print_delimiter:
    pushal
    mov     $delim, %eax
    push    %eax
    call    printf
    add     $4, %esp
    popal
    ret

read_line:
    pushal
    push    %ecx
    push    %edi
    push    $0
    call    read
    add     $12, %esp 
    xor     %edx, %edx
    movb    $0, (%edi,%eax)
    popal
    ret

read_hex:
    push    %ebp
    mov     %esp, %ebp
    sub     $4, %esp
    push    %ebx
    push    %ecx
    push    %edx

    lea -4(%ebp),%ebx
    push    %ebx
    push    $hex_
    call    scanf
    add     $8, %esp
    movl    (%ebx), %eax

    pop     %edx
    pop     %ecx
    pop     %ebx
    leave
    ret

read_dec:
    push    %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    subl $4, %esp
    lea -4(%ebp),%ebx
    pusha
    push    %ebx
    push    $dec_
    call    scanf
    add $8, %esp
    popa
    movl (%ebx), %eax
    leave
    ret

print_str:
    pushal
    push    %esi
    call    printf
    add $4, %esp
    popal
    ret

print_eax_binary:
    pushal
    movl $32, %ecx /* We print 32 digits. */

.print_digit:
        rol $1, %eax
        mov %eax,%edx
        and $1, %edx

        push %ecx
        push %eax

        push %edx
        push $hex_
        call printf
        add $8, %esp

        pop %eax
        pop %ecx

        loop .print_digit
    push $new_
    call printf
    add $4, %esp
    popal
    ret
```

Compiler fails.

```
$ gcc-9 -m32 strings.s -o strings
strings.s: Assembler messages:
strings.s:1: Error: missing string
```

Comment: Could you add the relevant portion of strings.s to the question directly instead of links.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow must be self-contained.  Please produce an [MCVE] and put it in your question.  Do not put links to code in your question.  Your question must still make sense when all sites you link to go down.

Comment: `movl  ARRLEN, %ecx` needs to be `$ARRLEN` because you want an immediate constant, not a load.

Comment: Not working still same error Peter

Comment: Note that gas can do intel syntax. Maybe not the same as yasm but probably easier to fix that than to switch to at&t.

Comment: Missing string I just don't know where I missed any strings

Comment: instead of doing the hard work of replacing register names and swapping the operands, just tell gas to use Intel syntax. [How do you use gcc to generate assembly code in Intel syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/199966/995714), [Can I use Intel syntax of x86 assembly with GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9347909/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the first line.  **GAS requires all strings (including file names) to be double-quoted.**

**`.include "fn.s"`** not `'fn.s'` single quotes.

---

**GAS doesn't accept multi-character character literals like `'abc'` as numeric literals either**, the way YASM and NASM do.  In fact it totally breaks parsing and it prints nonsense error messages.

```
.string 'abcd'

.include 'fn.s'


mov $'a', %eax
mov $'ab', %ax
.long 'abc'
```

```
strings.s: Assembler messages:
strings.s: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
strings.s:1: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `9'
strings.s:2: Error: missing string
strings.s:5: Error: backward ref to unknown label "97:"
strings.s:5: Error: junk `44%ax' after expression
strings.s:5: Error: number of operands mismatch for `mov'
strings.s:6: Error: backward ref to unknown label "97:"
strings.s:6: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `c'
```

Note that line 5 is blank, and the file *does* end with a newline (but it's at the end of a line containing a single quote.)

---

Single-character literals work as integers, like `add $'0', %eax` or `.long 'b'`.

Or in `.intel_syntax noprefix`, as `add eax, '0'`

---

**You should probably use `.intel_syntax noprefix`**

Mostly just put `OFFSET` into `mov reg, symbol` (making it `mov reg, OFFSET symbol`) to get the mov-immediate encoding, and port the directives.  Much easier and less error-prone than manually changing everything to AT&T syntax.